# Currency symbol: French franc

Tags: symbols

Is there a LaTeX symbol for French franc; the F-like symbol with a lower horizontal bar -- see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_franc?

I have had a look a both [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) and [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) without any luck.

**Update**

If I try the follwing, the symbol is not written; only `123` is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\fontspec{FreeSerif.otf}
\DeclareSIUnit{\franc}{^^^^20a3}

\begin{document}

\SI{123}{\franc}

\end{document}
```

How should I change the code?

Comment: I heard that someone once wanted to typeset it, but the French government brought suit against them for infringement of national sovereignty ;^)  p.s.  It does not appear to be in symbols-A4.pdf, the Symbol Bible

Comment: FYI: As far as I remember from the old days, I've never seen anything other than a plain F (no fancy bars) to denote Franc (in France).

Comment: `\normalfont` is still Latin Modern (set at `\begin{documnet}`), this font does not contain the symbol. See my updated answer.

Comment: I had never seen this symbol before (I'm French, and old enough to have known the franc). A quick search reveals that it had indeed been proposed in 1988, but never used. The standard abbreviation was a plain F at the time.

Comment: @AlexandreC. Hmmm. Okay. Thanks for the notice!

Comment: Don't use this symbol with a French audience: We've never ever seen it. Lol.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Unicode symbol for ₣ is:

```
U+20A3 FRENCH FRANC SIGN
```

Libertine is an example for a Unicode font that supports the character:

```
% lualatex or xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
\begin{document}
^^^^20a3 % ASCII notation
\end{document}
```

> [image: French Franc]

Example for GNU FreeFont:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\fontspec{FreeSerif.otf}
^^^^20a3
\end{document}
```

> [image: GNU FreeFont]

Another example for Times New Roman (from Windows 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\fontspec{times.ttf}
^^^^20a3
\end{document}
```

> [image: Times]

`\fontspec{Comfortaa-Regular.ttf}% Comfortaa Regular`:

> [image: Comfortaa]

`\fontspec{OpenSans-Regular.ttf}% Open Sans Regular`:

> [image: Open Sans]

### Example for `siunitx` and pdfLaTeX

If lualatex or pdflatex cannot be used, then the symbol can be included as graphics. The graphics is generated by:

```
% franc.tex
\nofiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\fontspec{FreeSerif.otf}
^^^^20a3
\end{document}
```

It is compiled via:

```
$ lualatex franc
$ pdfcrop franc
```

Then `franc-crop.pdf` can be used as image for pdfLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\myfranc}{\includegraphics[scale=.1]{franc}}
\DeclareSIUnit{\franc}{\myfranc}

\begin{document}
\SI{123.45}{\franc}
\end{document}
```

> [image: siunitx example]

If you are using lualatex or xelatex, then the font can be used directly, e.g.:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\myfranc}{%
  \begingroup
    \fontspec{FreeSerif.otf}%
    ^^^^20a3%
  \endgroup
}
```

Comment: Using `\fontspec` as a document command is not recommended.