# Removing ligatures when using fontspec

Tags: fontspec, ligatures

This is a follow-up question to [Currency symbol: French franc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103220/currency-symbol-french-franc).

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\myfranc}{%
  \begingroup
    \fontspec{FreeSerif.otf}%
    ^^^^20a3%
  \endgroup
}
\DeclareSIUnit{\franc}{\myfranc}

\begin{document}
Horse fififif \SI{123.45}{\franc}.
\end{document}
```

How do I remove the `fi` ligature to get a seperate `f` and `i` instead?

**Update**

A setup that works for me is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\myfranc}{%
  \begingroup
    \fontspec{FreeSerif.otf}%
    ^^^^20a3%
  \endgroup
}
\DeclareSIUnit{\franc}{\myfranc}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{
  Ligatures={
    NoCommon,
    NoRequired,
    NoContextual,
    NoHistoric,
    NoDiscretionary,
    TeX
  }
}
\setmainfont[
  BoldFont=lmroman10-bold.otf,
  ItalicFont=lmroman10-italic.otf,
  BoldItalicFont=lmroman10-bolditalic.otf,
  SlantedFont=lmromanslant10-regular.otf,
  BoldSlantedFont=lmromanslant10-bold.otf,
  SmallCapsFont=lmromancaps10-regular.otf
]{lmroman10-regular.otf}

\begin{document}
\section{Horse}
off fit fly office baffle -- \SI{123.456}{\franc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to suppress (i) just the `fi` ligature, (ii) *all* f-ligatures, or (iii) all typographic ligatures entirely? To suppress all so-called "Common" ligatures (generally f-ligatures), you could issue the command `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=NoCommon}` after loading `fontspec`.

Comment: For one off, the TeX book way would be `f\/i`.

Comment: @Mico: All typographic ligatures entirely.

Comment: Just saw your edit: Are you sure you want to enable `Discretionary` ligatures? For Latin Modern fonts, it of course doesn't matter since this font family provides only `Common` ligatures...

Comment: That was just to get the `--` ligature (so I didn't want all ligatures removed, anyway). What is the way to get the `--` and `---` ligatures and no one else?

Comment: @SvendMortensen - Be sure to specify `Ligatures={...,TeX}` to enable automated use of en- and em-dashes. (The default is `NoTeX`.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To suppress *all* typographic ligatures, you could issue the command

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={NoCommon, NoDiscretionary, NoHistoric, NoRequired, NoContextual}}
```

after loading the `fontspec` package. This directive will apply to all fonts selected subsequently in your document.

Comments:

- By far the most important option in the directive above is `NoCommon`. The so-called f-ligatures (ff, fi, fl, ffi, ffl, and possibly other f-ligatures as well) are generally assigned to the "Common" group.
- "Required" and "Contextual" are the defaults. However, virtually all OpenType fonts I'm familiar with do not feature any "Required" or "Contextual" ligatures. Thus, it's probably not necessary to specify "NoRequired" and "NoContextual", unless you use some kind of special font.
- "NoHistoric" and "NoDiscretionary" are the `fontspec` defaults. However, it doesn't hurt to specify these options explicitly to make your intentions clear, right? :-)

*Addendum*: Here's an MWE that illustrates the use of the `\defaultfontfeatures` command when used with XeLaTeX:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={NoCommon, NoRequired, NoContextual, NoHistoric, NoDiscretionary}}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
  % If your TeX distribution/Operating System doesn't recognize "logical" font names
  % such as "Latin Modern Roman", try using the name of the file that contains the 
  % font you're trying to load. In this case, try "\setmainfont{lmroman10-regular.otf}".

\begin{document}
off fit fly office baffle 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This still results in ligatures for me. Could you post a MEW, please? (P.S. I use `xelatex`.)

Comment: @SvendMortensen If you don't specify a font with `\setmainfont` the default (with ligatures enabled) will be used. As Mico says, the `\defaultfontfeatures` declarations are applied to *subsequently loaded* fonts.

Comment: @SvendMortensen - Please see the MWE I've added per your request.

Comment: @Mico I don't really understand this. When I compile, I get the folllowing error: `Invalid fontname 'Latin Modern Roman', contains ' '


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Latin Modern Roman" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  
                                                  
l.4 \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
                                     % "Latin Modern" only features "Common"...`

Comment: @SvendMortensen -- Which TeX distribution and which operating system do you use? (I happen to use `MacTeX2012` running under MacOSX 10.7.5., and my XeTeX version is labeled `3.1415926-2.4-0.9998`, dated 2013.02.28.) Could you check if the MWE works on your system if you replace `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}` with `\setmainfont{lmroman10-regular.otf}`, i.e., if you replace the font's logical name with the name of the file that contains the font?

Comment: Now it works. `:)` Thanks for your patients and help! P.S. I use an up-to-date version of TeX Live 2012.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{lmroman10-regular.otf}
\newfontface\Franc{FreeSerif.otf}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit{\kroner}{kr.}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\myfranc}{{\Franc^^^^20a3}}
\DeclareSIUnit{\franc}{\myfranc}

\begin{document}
Horse fififif \SI{123.45}{\franc}.
\end{document}
```

btw: define a font face instead of running `\fontspec`

Comment: What do you mean by "running `\fontspec`"?

Comment: sorry, I meant _using_ `\fontspec`