# Xelatex beamer Calibri: how to suppress unwanted ligatures

Tags: beamer, fonts, xetex, ligatures

Solution:

```
\setsansfont[Ligatures={NoRequired,NoCommon,NoContextual}]{Calibri}
```

I'm no typographer, therefore I didn't know the techinical terms, but this Wikipedia article describes it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature#Stylistic_ligat

I would like to use Calibri with the beamer class but I get very strange merges of the terminal letters with a vertical bar, e.g. ti almost becomes a ligature, see picture.

[image]

This behavior of Calibri is not reproducible in Word.

Working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setsansfont{Calibri Bold}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\setmathrm{Cambria Math}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
\begin{frame}
\section{Section 1}
Eine Definition
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Regardless of the problem, Word is not a valid yardstick for typographical properties. I guess this is kind of related http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13484/use-advanced-font-ligatures-in-office-2010/

Comment: It doesn't "almost" become a ligature, it just becomes one. Calibri has some ligatures, and there are ways to enable automatic ligatures in Word. LaTeX inserts them by default.

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Removing ligatures when using fontspec](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103238/5001)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, these are ligatures which LaTeX uses by default, but Word doesn't - so this is actually the intended behavior as designed by the creators of the font! If you want to disable them, you can do so by using the [`fontspec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) option `Ligatures=NoCommon`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Calibri Bold}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\setmathrm{Cambria Math}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
\begin{frame}
\section{Section 1}
Eine Definition
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: the sample text "Eine Definition" in Calibri Bold without ligatures]