# \DeclareUnicodeCharacter and LuaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, unicode, input-encodings

Is there an equivalent command to `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` for LuaTeX that allows me to define alias commands for special UTF-8/Unicode characters? I am using a custom Fraktur font that uses Unicode's private use area for the definition of ligatures.

I can enter those characters into my editor (Sublime Text 2) using copy-and-paste. LuaTeX correctly displays the ligatures in the output, but in the editor they are displayed as empty rectangles. This makes the source code hard to read.

I know that in pdfLaTeX you can define commands for Unicode characters using

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{hexcode}{\alias}
```

so you can simply write `\alias` instead of the Unicode character itself.

But this approuch doesn't work for LuaTeX. Is there another way to achieve this?

You can find the Fraktur font (Normalfraktur UNZ1-genormt) [on this website (German)](http://www.ligafaktur.de/Schriften.html).

Comment: I had a similar question to a font with musical symbols. So maybe that answer can help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180355/46389

Comment: \DeclareUnicodeCharacter doesn't define \alias, it uses it. If you want to define \alias to do something, use simply \newcommand\alias{your char}.

Comment: Looks like what you really need is the contrary of what you are asking for... Apparently you can enter directly the utf-8 chars in your editor, and they appear right in the resulting pdf, but the problem is that your editor doesn't show those glyphs. You need to set a font in the editor which has those glyps.

Comment: @musicman Thanks for the link. I'll have a look at it. @Ulrike Fischer: So I misunderstood `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`. @JLDiaz No. Having to use a Fraktur font in my text editor would be odd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With LuaTeX or XeTeX simply use that character:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\def\alias{\symbol{"00BB}}
\begin{document}
$\char"2B33$ » \alias $\mbfscrF$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It didn't work immediately for me, since I tried with `\symbol{"F1BB}`, which gives an error. I had to add zero, first, `\symbol{"0F1BB}` and now it works perfectly.

Comment: @pvorb You probably have `babel` shortcuts active; `\symbol{\string"F1BB}` should do.

Comment: I thought it was more kosher to use ``\newcommand`` in ``LaTeX`` rather than ``\def``?