# Why does microtype claim that it cannot disable ligatures?

Tags: xetex, microtype, ligatures

The package `microtype` claims that it cannot disable ligatures because that would require pdftex version 1.30 or newer:

```
! Package microtype Error: Disabling ligatures of a font is only possible
(microtype)                with pdftex version 1.30 or newer.
(microtype)                Ignoring \DisableLigatures.
```

`pdftex -v` gives

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
[...]
```

So which pdftex version is this?

---

Additional information: The first line of the log is

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2017.1.15)  25 APR 2017 11:04
```

(I need to compile with `xelatex` as required by the `fontspec` package.)

Comment: It's a newer version. But what version is used by your document? What does the first line of the log-file says?

Comment: `microtype` provides only protrusion for XeLaTeX.

Comment: The version of `pdftex` you are looking at is `1.40.16`, the `3.14..` is the underlying tex version.

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewSwann -- as the problem turned out to be unrelated to the version, I'll make this a different question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have a look at the [`microtype` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf) you will find:

[image]

The box with the information "pdfTeX 1.30.0|LuaTeX 0.30" tells you, that disabling ligatures with `microtype` does only work for pdfTeX from version 1.30.0 or LuaTeX from 0.30. You are using XeTeX not pdfTeX, so `microtype` does not provide disabling ligatures. But [`fontspec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) does also provide features for ligatures, e.g., font option `Ligatures=NoCommon`. See [Removing ligatures when using fontspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103238/removing-ligatures-when-using-fontspec).

Comment: Thanks for solving my actual problem. Hmmm, I wonder whether I should edit the question to match the answer...

Comment: I was extremely confused by the question, because as it stands now, the title has nothing to do with the question. I suggest either a rollback or that the content of the question is changed.

Comment: @Sverre: If you think so, do the rollback. But the title just repeats the first sentence as an question. So it shouldn't be confusing. And the tags now are much more convenient than before.

Comment: btw: I have added the actual error message. As it stands now, title and question look consistent.