# Disabling specific ligatures fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ligatures

I made changes to something in an (English language) .tex file and discovered all my ss now exported as ß.  After some debugging in my version control, there was no clear culprit to undo (maybe a font changed?), so I have turned to patching the problem over.

I'm consulting:

- [Why does microtype claim that it cannot disable ligatures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366574/why-does-microtype-claim-that-it-cannot-disable-ligatures/366576)
- [Removing ligatures when using fontspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103238/removing-ligatures-when-using-fontspec)
- https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec

I'm using the following, NoCommon, to disable ligatures:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,
                     Ligatures={NoCommon}}
```

Can I be more targeted than disabling all ligatures?  Is it possible to disable /only/ the ss ligature when using fontspec with xelatex?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "all my ss [are] now exported as ß". Do you mean to say that "ss" gets typeset as ß"? (The verb "export" has many potential meanings...) Incidentally, are your free to switch from XeLaTeX to LuaLaTeX? If so, you might want to take a look at the [selnolig](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/selnolig?lang=en) package.

Comment: does that work? I would expect that `NoCommon` disables `ffi` ligatures but I wouldn't have expected `ss->ß` to be in the Common ligature set?

Comment: Weird, right?  My PDF rendered acceß, neceßary, etc., just from having contiguous s in text.  Changing to this did actually fix it, but I wonder if I'm missing out on other potentially nice ligatures.  It seems like oe stays, fwiw.

Comment: What font is that? Even for a german text this wouldn't be a suitable behaviour.