# Currency symbol: French franc II

Tags: symbols, fontspec

This is a follow-up question to [Currency symbol: French franc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103220/currency-symbol-french-franc).

Consider ther following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\myfranc}{%
  \begingroup
    \fontspec{FreeSerif.otf}%
    ^^^^20a3%
  \endgroup
}
\DeclareSIUnit{\franc}{\myfranc}

\setmainfont[
  BoldFont = lmroman10-bold.otf,
  ItalicFont = lmroman10-italic.otf,
  BoldItalicFont = lmroman10-bolditalic.otf,
  SlantedFont = lmromanslant10-regular.otf,
  BoldSlantedFont = lmromanslant10-bold.otf,
  SmallCapsFont = lmromancaps10-regular.otf
]{lmroman10-regular.otf}


\begin{document}

\SI{1000}{\franc}

\end{document}
```

This (which is Heiko Oberdiek's last suggestion in his [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103226/15874)) has previously worked but it doesn't anymore; only the quantity, and not the unit (French franc symbol), is now printed. How do I fix this?

Also,  how do I remove the following font warning?

> Command `\normalsize` invalid in math mode on input line 26.

Comment: Surely not `\fontspec`!

Comment: @egreg That was Heiko's suggestion. Can I make you create an answer to fix the problem? `:)`

Comment: May be `\myfranc` is prepared to be used in text mode and `siunitx` uses it inside math-mode? If so, `\text{…}` or `\textnormal{…}` or `\mbox{…}`…

Comment: @Manuel The math/text mode was indeed the issue. I just had to use `\DeclareSIUnit[mode = text]{\franc}{\myfranc}`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Nice. You should post an answer, because that seems to be the official solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command `\fontspec` should never be used in a document; define a font family and use that.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\myfranc}{%
  \mbox{\freeserif^^^^20a3}%
}
\DeclareSIUnit{\franc}{\myfranc}

\setmainfont[
  BoldFont = lmroman10-bold.otf,
  ItalicFont = lmroman10-italic.otf,
  BoldItalicFont = lmroman10-bolditalic.otf,
  SlantedFont = lmromanslant10-regular.otf,
  BoldSlantedFont = lmromanslant10-bold.otf,
  SmallCapsFont = lmromancaps10-regular.otf
]{lmroman10-regular.otf}
\newfontfamily{\freeserif}{FreeSerif.otf}

\begin{document}

\SI{1000}{\franc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also input `₣` directly, if you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont[
  BoldFont = lmroman10-bold.otf,
  ItalicFont = lmroman10-italic.otf,
  BoldItalicFont = lmroman10-bolditalic.otf,
  SlantedFont = lmromanslant10-regular.otf,
  BoldSlantedFont = lmromanslant10-bold.otf,
  SmallCapsFont = lmromancaps10-regular.otf
]{lmroman10-regular.otf}
\newfontfamily{\freeserif}{FreeSerif.otf}

\newunicodechar{₣}{\text{\freeserif ₣}}
\newcommand{\FF}{₣}
\DeclareSIUnit{\franc}{\FF}

\begin{document}

\SI{1000}{\franc} is 1000\,₣ or \SI{1000}{₣}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: looks vaguely like a guillotine...

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the problem occured because v2.6 of [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) switches standard setting for mode option from `text` to `math`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\myfranc}{% thanks to egreg and Manuel
  \begingroup
   \freeserif^^^^20a3%
  \endgroup
}
\DeclareSIUnit[mode = text]{\franc}{\myfranc}

\newfontfamily{\freeserif}{FreeSerif.otf}

\begin{document}

\SI{1000}{\franc}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Still, using `\fontspec` is wrong. Look why in the manual.

Comment: @egreg I'm not sure where to look in the [manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf); can you tell me where? P.S. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg You should put it in a group, in case you don't want to change the font: `{\freeserif^^^^20a3}` or `\begingroup\freeserif^^^^20a3\endgroup`.

Comment: Page 7: “For cases when a specific font with a specific feature set is going to be re-used many times in a document, it is inefficient to keep calling `\fontspec` for every use. While the `\fontspec` command does not define a new font instance after the first call, the feature options must still be parsed and processed.”